# Can the scroll go down every time i reload the page?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Hello guys im implementing a chat, the issue is that every time that i reload the page the scroll is always on the top of the chat and i want on the bottom, i tried with jquery but doesnt work.

This is my html:

```
<body>
<div class="chatbox">
    <div class="chatlogs">
        <div class="chat friend">
            <div class="user-photo"></div>
            <p class="chat-message">What's up, Brother ..!!</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="chat friend">
            <div class="user-photo"></div>
            <p class="chat-message">What's up, Brother ..!!</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="chat self">
            <div class="user-photo"></div>
            <p class="chat-message">What's up ..!!</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="chat self">
            <div class="user-photo"></div>
            <p class="chat-message">A única área que eu acho, que vai exigir muita atenção nossa, e aí eu já aventei a hipótese de até criar um ministério. É na área de... Na área... Eu diria assim, como uma espécie de analogia com o que acontece na área agrícola.</p>    
        </div>
        <div class="chat friend">
            <div class="user-photo"></div>
            <p class="chat-message">No meu xinélo da humildade eu gostaria muito de ver o Neymar e o Ganso. Por que eu acho que.... 11 entre 10 brasileiros gostariam. Você veja, eu já vi, parei de ver. Voltei a ver, e acho que o Neymar e o Ganso têm essa capacidade de fazer a gente olhar.

            Todos as descrições das pessoas são sobre a humanidade do atendimento, a pessoa pega no pulso, examina, olha com carinho. Então eu acho que vai ter outra coisa, que os médicos cubanos trouxeram pro brasil, um alto grau de humanidade.
            </p>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-form">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button>Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #1ddced;
}

.chatbox {
    width: 500px;
    min-width: 390px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 3px #ccc;
}

.chatlogs {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chatlogs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

.chatlogs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.chat {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.chat .user-photo {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.chat .chat-message {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 10px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.friend .chat-message {
    background: #1adda4;
}

.self .chat-message {
    background: #1ddced;
    order: -1;
}

.chat-form {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.chat-form textarea {
    background: #fbfbfb;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    resize: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
}

.chat-form textarea:focus {
    background: #fff;
}

.chat-form button {
    background: #1ddced;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #0eb2c1;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transaction: background .2s ease;
    -moz-transaction: backgroud .2s ease;
    -o-transaction: backgroud .2s ease;
}

.chat-form button:hover {
    background: #13c8d9;
}
```

One more question, can i block horizontal scroll not only hide.
I hope you guys can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're primarily looking for the javascript native scrollIntoView function. Though in lieu of anything else you'll still need jQuery for finding your element to scroll to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.chat.friend').last()[0].scrollIntoView();
})
```

Cool options such as smooth scrolling and compatibility at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

As for blocking horizontal slide, I'm not quite sure what you mean. You've already got it wrapping words appropriately. If you're looking to prevent very long words or URLs from going off the edge, then look into https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp, e.g.,

```
word-break: break-all;
```

If you're meaning images, then you'll need to see the max-width property for images

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The last message can be from friend or self i tried and still not working :c

Comment: Probably best to post a jsfiddle for things like this. E.g., working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zj8p4s0L/. Compare this to your page and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` in your page declaration. Setting this to true will keep the user at the same place on the screen after a postback occurs.

You can read more about it [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @SteveFest. I'll keep that in mind in the future.